# Django: Initial modelform fields with the same name

Tags: django, django-forms

I got a `ModelForm` with some ajax actions that create fields like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myfield" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="myfield" value="2" />
```

I'm fine saving these data as `ManyToMany` using `request.POST.getlist('myfield')`, but I can't seem to initialize the hidden input fields on the update view.

What I got so far:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myfield = forms.Field('Some field')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModelForm

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        other_models = OtherModel.objects.filter(mymodelform=kwargs['instance'])
```

So now, how can I include each of the `other_models` of `__init__` as hidden fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add model forms fields dynamically in this fashion.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myfield = forms.Field('Some field')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModelForm

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        instance = kwargs.pop('instance')    
        other_models = OtherModel.objects.filter(mymodelform=instance)

        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i, other_model in enumerate(other_models):
            self.fields['other_model_field_{i}'.format(i=i)] = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(), initial=other_model.name)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what about using the same `other_model` on the `name` attribute of every hidden input tag?

Comment: you would specify the initial attribute. check the edt.

Comment: Sort of. I had to do some other modifications due to my project, but I'm marking your answer as accepted. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Great. Feedback always helps in providing better answers in the future.. :) Thanks